# How to establish communication between the mouse filter driver and the MFC

Tags: c++, filter, mfc, driver, mouse

I don't know English, so I use google translate.
The problem is this. I am writing a project - a mouse filter driver that passes the coordinates of the cursor to the program. The program, in turn, reads them and produces a file that can be sent to Excel, where you can see the trajectory of the mouse movement.
But this is still a long way off, but for now I cannot simply transfer data to the program.

```
typedef struct _MOU_OUTPUT_DATA {
    USHORT LastX;
    USHORT LastY;
} MOU_OUTPUT_DATA, *PMOU_OUTPUT_DATA;

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    devicehandle = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\MyMouLink", GENERIC_, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
    if (devicehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MessageBox(L"not valid value", 0, 0);
        return;
    }
    MessageBox(L"valid value", 0, 0);
}

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    if (devicehandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MessageBox(L"Error", 0, 0);
    }
    else {
        CloseHandle(devicehandle);
        MessageBox(L"Ok", 0, 0);
    }
}
```

This is the code for my MFC program. Only 2 buttons connect and disconnect, and as it is clear from the code, `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is always true.

```
NTSTATUS DispatchPass(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP Irp) 
{   
    NTSTATUS status;
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION irpsp = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(Irp);

    switch (irpsp->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode)
    {
    case IRP_MJ_CREATE:
        KdPrint(("Create request \r\n"));
        break;
    case IRP_MJ_READ:
        KdPrint(("Read request \r\n"));
        break;
    case IRP_MJ_WRITE:
        KdPrint(("Write request \r\n"));
        break;
    default:
        status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
        KdPrint(("INVALID PARAMETER \r\n"));
        break;
    }
    return IoCallDriver(((PDEVICE_EXTENSION)DeviceObject->DeviceExtension)->MyUSB_Device, Irp);
}
```

This part of the code is called in the driver and called

```
for (int i = 0; i < IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION;i++) {
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[i] = DispatchPass;
    }
```

I hope you understand :D

```
NTSTATUS MyAttachDevice(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
NTSTATUS status;
UNICODE_STRING MCName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Driver\\mouclass");
PDRIVER_OBJECT targetDriverObject = NULL;
PDEVICE_OBJECT currentDeviceObject = NULL;
PDEVICE_OBJECT myDeviceObject = NULL;
status = ObReferenceObjectByName(&MCName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, 0, 
*IoDriverObjectType, KernelMode, NULL, (PVOID*)&targetDriverObject);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
    KdPrint(("ObReference failed \r\n"));
    return status;
}

ObDereferenceObject(targetDriverObject);

currentDeviceObject = targetDriverObject->DeviceObject;

while (currentDeviceObject) {

    status = IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION), NULL, 
    FILE_DEVICE_MOUSE, 0, FALSE, &myDeviceObject);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        //do your work
        return status;
    }
    RtlZeroMemory(myDeviceObject->DeviceExtension, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION));
    status = IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStackSafe(myDeviceObject, 
    currentDeviceObject, &((PDEVICE_EXTENSION)myDeviceObject- 
    >DeviceExtension)->LowerKbdDevice);
    
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        //IoDeleteDevice(myDeviceObject);
        //do your work
        return status;
    }


    myDeviceObject->Flags |= DO_BUFFERED_IO;
    myDeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;

    currentDeviceObject = currentDeviceObject->NextDevice;
}

return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: After `CreateFile` use `GetLastError` to get the reason that the file could not be opened.

Comment: Hey! If trust this function, then I have error 0x2. This is "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: How does your driver create the `MyMouLink` device?  (Show code if possible) Are you adding a symbolic link to the proper location?  For example:  `\Device\MyMouLink`

Comment: The problem has been resolved. It was all about my Attach method. I don't know why, but IoCreateDevice did not create the device. P,S, I added some code, see above.